# setting UILabel.text of a custom UITableViewCell inside ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I am populating with custom `UITableViewCell` in interface builder. I am having some issues accessing these custom tableviewcells properties and am hoping for some help.

In Interface Builder I am setting the custom tableviewcell's `class` to the current View controller (so I can assign all of the label objects to the correct labels in Interface Builder), So I have also set up the `IBOutlet` labels to the correct labels in Interface Builder However this error occurs when I try to pass the NSString from the array object variable (which is of type NSString) to the UIlabel's text.

```
Property 'cellDescription' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'
```

Below is the code I have used to set up my tableview with the custom tableviewcell and then try to populate the cells UILabels with the correct text..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {      
        // Set cell height
        [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell using custom cell
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AutomotiveSearchCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = autoSearchCell;

        //call dataArrayOfObject that has all of the values you have to apply to the custom tableviewcell
        SearchResultItem* myObj = (SearchResultItem*)[dataArrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.cellDescription.text = myObj.seriesDescription; // This is where I am receiving the error

        NSLog(@"%@", myObj.seriesDescription); // This logs the correct value

        //Disclosure Indicator
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must typeCasting `UITableViewCell` To `AutomotiveSearchCell`

I think you code somewhere is strange(There is no declaration for autoSearchCell), but you must do the following.

```
cell = (AutomotiveSerachCell* )autoSearchCell;
```

The above code does not work, should following code.

---

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

convert to

```
AutomotiveSearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

---

If that does not work above, refer a following process.

1. make a CustomCell Class.
   [image]
2. make a CustomCell xib.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. linked label to CustomCell Class.
   [image]
4. import header `#import "AutomotiveSearchCell.h"` and following code copy and paste.

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AutomotiveSearchCell *cell = nil;

    if(!cell)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AutomotiveSearchCell" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *arr = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.cellDescription.text = @"Test~!~!~!";
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hrmm.. its coming up with `expected expression` on the closing bracket.. do I need to call this outside of the if statment?

Comment: I edited post. check out please. If i see your full code i give to clearly answer.

Comment: hrmm, it seems that changnig it from UITableViewCell to AutomotiveSearchCell gives me this error when ever I try to use `cell` **/Users/imac/Documents/Iphone applications/ii//MSeriesViewController.m:154:27: Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'**

Comment: Are you import 'AutomotiveSearchCell.h'? My code is no problem. recheck please. `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` convert to `AutomotiveSearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Comment: ah, AutomotiveSearchCell is only .xib I have passed currentViewController as the xibs class so i declare all of the UIabels in my current class but my AutomotiveSearchCell.xib can see the declared UILabels from currentViewController

Comment: AutomotiveSerchCell is not have a class? only have a xib? why? i recommend make a AutomotiveSerchCell.h and AutomotiveSerchCell.m. and you should linked to AutomotiveSerchCell Class all Labels. it's common sense.

Comment: well I have changed AutomotiveSerchCell class to the class that owns the uitableview. all of the IBOutlets can then be declared inside the same class as the tableview and linked up in the customcell.xib..

Comment: turns out all I had to do was drop the `cell` from **cell.cellDescription.text = myObj.seriesDescription; // This is where I am receiving the error** and it worked... dang nabit... thanks for the help

Comment: I edited post. recheck please. i will willing be happy to help forever.